# SQL Server : see a user activity

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way to track my user's activity (number of SQL queries...)?

And is there a way to see people tracking my activity in SQL Server?

Comment: There is something called Server Audit that you can turn on to track activity like this. There is also tracing that can be turned on. As for the second part, it depends on your privileges on the SQL Server. If you are sysadmin, you can see if any of these are in place. If you aren't sysadmin (or if you don't in any other way have privileges to look), then you won't know.

Answer (score 0):

Using extended events you could track logins and query activity. This can be filtered appropriately.